# jmeter report created using ant xslt does not show max min value

Tags: java, xml, xslt, ant, jmeter

Environment Details:

Jmeter 2.10,

Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2,

Java 6 SE build1.6.0_34b04,

jdk1.7.0_17,

Windows 8

When i open the jmeter-results-detail-report.xsl in IE I get the max and min values.

but when i use ant and create html report using the same jmeter-results-detail-report.xsl it does not show any max and min values.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following to your `xslt` task which generates HTML report

```
<param name="show-Data" expression="${show-data}"/>
```

Where `show-data` can be defined as follows:

```
<property name="show-data" value="y"/>
```

taking value of `y` or `n`

However it may have a negative impact on overall performance as in certain configurations it will trigger saving response data as well. I would recommend to use [results analysis plugin listener](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/83191-blazemeter-plugin-to-jmeter) instead.